# Closed form for $(2^1-1)(2^2-1)...(2^k-1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, products

> Is there closed form for $\prod_1^{i=k}(2^i-1)$ ?

I found that it is the product of the terms of the following arithmetico-geometric sequence :
$$\{u_1=1,u_{n+1}=2u_n+1\}$$
I found nothing with factorials, but there may be something.

For the story, I want to prove that :
$$\forall n \in \Bbb N, n\gt 3, \exists m \in \Bbb N, 0 \lt m \lt n$$
such as $$\forall k \in \Bbb N, 0 \lt k \lt n^2-m²-2n+1, 2^k \not\equiv 1 \mod (n^2-m^2)$$
and $$2^{n^2-m^2-2n+1} \equiv 1 \mod (n^2-m^2)$$
That's why I tried to make the product.

Comment: You might check the limits on the product.

Comment: What do you mean by « check the limits » ? Find its convergence ?

Comment: You have $\prod_{1}^{i=k}$. This doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean $\prod_{i=1}^k(2^i-1)$?

Comment: I made a typo. Fixed !

Comment: I don't think this question suffers from a lack of 'context or details'... :/ And even if it did, there's no need to vote to close it immediately.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A005329 has no simpler formula.

Comment: A short form is $[k]_2!$, where $[k]_q!$ is the $q$-analogue of the factorial function.

Comment: Yes, @Batominovski, I found that also, but I don't know how to use it in my problem (added the complete problem).

Comment: @Klave I think $m=n-1$ solves the problem.

Comment: @Batominovski How do you prove the penultimate equation ?

Comment: You don't, since you will get $0<k<0$.  Hence, that statement is true vacuously.

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, indeed. Thanks a lot for your help, @Batominovski !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of known notations:

Let $u_{n+1} = 2 \, u_{n} + 1$ where $u_{0}=1$, for which $u_{n} = 2^{n}-1$.
Using 
$$(x;q)_{n} = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 - x \, q^{r})$$
leads to
\begin{align}
P_{n} &= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \{ u_{k} \} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \{ 2^{k+1} - 1 \} \\
&= 2^{\binom{n+1}{2}} \, \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{k}}\right) \\
&= 2^{\binom{n+1}{2}} \, \left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}.
\end{align}

Comment: I found this notation, but @Leucippus, how can I use it to easily compute the product ?

Comment: There is not much else to do. These numbers presented here are called the "2-factorial numbers" and are given by [A005329](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C21%2C315%2C9765&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Answer (score 3):

The (Gauss) $q$-analogue of the binomial theorem expresses the product of terms $(1 - q^i)$ as a sum whose terms are (up to some normalization factors) $q$-binomial coefficients.

Formulas are listed at *Gaussian binomial coefficients* in Wikipedia, for example.